# Visual Studio в Unity открывается на половину.

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity3d

При открытии скрипта в Unity, окно загрузки не исчезает, а Visual Studio не показывает дополнительные окна, как "Обозреватель решения".
http://screenshot.su/img/2b/d3/b6/2bd3b680e08a28e2a994c826b0bb9b25.jpg

Comment: [VS Tools for Unity](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/unitytools-vs.aspx) установлены?

Comment: Неа, но раньше всё работало и было супер. Только сегодня так.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обозреватель решения и прочие окна могли просто отключиться, но их включить всегда можно через меню сверху, где можно настроить отображение всех нужных окон.

Процесс открытия могнекорректно завершиться из-за сбоя нового процесса. Несколько раз похожее было. Приходилось перезапускать процесс и студии, и юнити.

Лучше всего обновите юнити и студию. И если есть возможность - запускайте приложения от имени администратора.

Answer (score 0):

Есть подобная история. VS через Юньку открывается наполовину, в диспетчере задач убиваешь его(он там 0% процессора ест), снова открываешь через Юньку - открывается. Видимо, некой общий баг. Возможно, стоит дождаться большого обновления, может уберут.

Answer (score 0):

У меня была подобная проблема, но решение вообще не открывалось. Только пустая студия и блокнот с кодом. 
Снял с devenv.exe галочку "запускать от имени админа". Все стало ок. Судя по всему Unity проверяет успешность запуска VS, а из-за окна разрешения - решила, что VS запустить не удалось.